# Custom Class with Constraint Layout, Android Studio HANGS

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to implement a custom class that implements ConstraintLayout, but the problem is that when I try to use this in XML the Android Studio just hangs, everything freezes, you can't do anything, you can just close the Studio through the Task Manager. Then you reopen, but if you open that XML file, it is the same story again.

I get this:
Preview timed out while rendering the layout. This typically happens when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views.

Basically first i designed the UI through ConstraintLayout, then i tried just replacing ConstraintLayout with this Class, and then when it tries to render it just freezes. I can't give much code because of NDA.

Class:

```
    public class ExtraView extends ConstraintLayout {

        public ExtraView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        public ExtraView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
        }

        public ExtraView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            init(context);
        }

        public void init(Context context){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_extra_rent_booking, this, true);
            Butterknife.bind(this,v);
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<package.ExtraView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rentExtraLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            style="@style/contentTextDark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/gps_extra" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_checkmark_dark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
            style="@style/contentTextDark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/checkImageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameTextView"
            tools:text="+xx€" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lineSplitting"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTextView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/expandViewLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lineSplitting"></LinearLayout>
</package.ExtraView>
```

This will make Android Studio hang and the app will crash when opening this xml. But with ConstraintLayout it works. What am i doing wrong? I've got latest libraries downloaded.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yup everything freezes still...

Answer (score 2):

I re-read the conversation again and realized that you just wanted the layout presented to be a RecycleView item. I was telling you about the fragments because I thought you wanted to put a list of data in your extra view. (So my apologies for that :/)

If you want to keep this sequence of views for several uses, this is the best choice to make a personalized view.

- **For a personalized view**, the problem is to build your view with the pattern. To do this, one way is to do it manually because you have a sequence of views on one level.

  ```
  public class ExtraView extends ConstraintLayout {

     private TextView mText = null;
     ...

     public void init(Context context){
         int wrapContent = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         int matchParent = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
         setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(matchParent, wrapContent));
         mText = new TextView(getContext());

         addView(mText, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent));

         ... // Do the same thing for all elements with parameters

     }
  }
  ```

After that add your *`addExtra`* method, and it's ok, no more loop and you can use it where you want and in your **onBindViewHolder** with only one line.

**Edit** :

Work with your actual layout XML if you replace the root node, **full exemple** :

**Extraview.java** *file*

```
public class ExtraView extends ConstraintLayout {

    public ExtraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ExtraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ExtraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_extra_rent_booking, this, true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    }

    public void addData(Object data) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), object.toString());
    }
}
```

**view_extra_rent_booking.xml** *file*

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rentExtraLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="test" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/checkImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameTextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/checkImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:text="test" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/lineSplitting"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTextView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandViewLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lineSplitting">   
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Main activity is for sample but in real it's you *holder* who get the view in *onBindViewHolder()*

**activity_main.xml** *file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.kunzisoft.myapplication.ExtraView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kunzisoft.myapplication.MainActivity" />
```

**MainActivity.java** *file*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ExtraView itemData = (ExtraView) findViewById(R.id.item);
        itemData.addData("OUIIIIIII");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 Question, why can't i just inflate the view and then try to bind it with butterknife or findingViewById, surely there is a better way than recreating the all the elements, because the XML is already ready now it just needs to be ready to use, but here is like there is no xml. Thank you so you finnaly understand what i was trying to tell you :)

Comment: Yeh try with your class like in the question and replace **package.ExtraView**  by **merge**. The root should merge with ConstraintLayout

Comment: And sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language! ^^'

Comment: But if you do merge, instead of package.ExtraView, don't you lose all constraints? I've never used merge before that's why i'm asking. No problem :) mine isn't either.

Comment: I don't know, for me if the parameters are in the child views, this will be used when adding in root. It doesn't work when you test ?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet because i'm not at home. It is just me speculating, but how would you get for example if he clicked this ExtraView? 
(ExtraView) getRootView() or something?

Comment: It's like any view, you can add an id in the merge and retrieve it with a findViewById. You should create a small project to test, it costs nothing

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work :( whenever i try to put this custom class into XML it crashes

Comment: I also tested and it works great for me, do you put the package name when you call your view in the XML?

Comment: I'll try again :)

Comment: Can you please share the example because i can't get it to work

Comment: Nope... i'm going to change it to RelativeLayout and see if it works

Comment: It didn't work, I'll try something with BindViewHolder and leave it in RelativeLayout to see something will report right back

Comment: The still crashes in the xml, but i did it, in OnCreateViewHolder:
        return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(new ExtraView(parent.getContext())) {};
and then in BindViewHolder you can cast it normally, so it works :)